# Creating a function to pair the corresponding elements in 2 lists

Tags: dictionary, scheme, lisp, racket, fold

I am learning to use scheme and practicing by creating functions from practice problems I saw in a book. This one is called `zipper`. 
I have already made the `zipper` function using recursion with only `cons`, `car`, and `cdr`. 
Now I am trying to make this same function again but also using `map` or `fold`. 
The function takes in two lists and 'zips' them together:

```
 (zip '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
 ==> '((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

How can I do this using either `map` or `fold`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may become clearer if the function to be used by map is declared separately:

```
(define (zip1 x y)
  (list x y))

(map zip1 '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) ; corresponding elements of 2 lists will be sent to zip1
```

Since zip1 is only 'list', following also works:

```
(map list '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
```

Output for both:

```
'((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))
```

Hence to do `(zip L1 L2)`, one does not need to write special `zip` function, one can just do `(map list L1 L2)`.

This can also be used for any number of lists, e.g. `(map list L1 L2 L3 L4)` which may be an advantage over custom-made zip function made for 2 lists only.

Answer (score 0):

The Racket documentation for [map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=fold#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) provides the following example:

```
> (map (lambda (number1 number2)
         (+ number1 number2))
       '(1 2 3 4)
       '(10 100 1000 10000))
'(11 102 1003 10004)
```

Notice that this is very similar to what you are trying to achieve, but instead of mapping the `+` function between corresponding elements in two lists, you can map a `list` function, as follows:

```
> (map (lambda (number1 number2)
         (list number1 number2))
       '(1 2 3 4)
       '(10 100 1000 10000))
'((1 10) (2 100) (3 1000) (4 10000))
```

and hence, a zip function becomes:

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (map
   (lambda(elem1 elem2)
     (list elem1 elem2))
   lst1 lst2))
```